# checkbox checked or unchecked based on the value Display?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

i  am using check box results input page i have check box code looks like

```
   <input name="upfrontMIPPc" id="upfrontMIPPc1" type="text" class="txt" size="3" maxlength="3" onChange="javascript:upfrontMIPPcChanged(true)" />

 <div class="col-md-1 padding-lft" style="right:13px;top:3px">
      <input id="chkUFtoLoan-1" name="S"  type="checkbox" /> 
    </div>
```

this check box name pass another page i have using php file i  have used post method
Looks like

```
 $S = $_POST["S"];
```

Results i have two section of value of check box

```
 1.About Your Loan

 2.Buyer Cost To Close
```

Check box input fields name value upfront MIP.
if the user checked the Include In Calc button from the input page.
They should all be defaulted to checked (as we are defaulting to adding the UPFRONT MIP balance to the loan).

- But if they uncheck the checkboxes, then the value gets placed in the Buyer Costs To Close Section?
- how to display value depends check box checked or unchecked ?

  MY js fiddle Link :  https://jsfiddle.net/2dgp0drd/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var check;    
    // Example 1 - With checked
    $("#test1").on("click", function(){
        if(checkbox1.checked) {
            alert("checked.");
        } else {
            alert("unchecked.");
        }
    });  

    // Example 2 - With jQuery is, NOTE - :checked
    $("#test2").on("click", function(){
        check = $("#checkbox1").is(":checked");
        if(check) {
            alert("checked.");
        } else {
            alert("unchecked.");
        }
    });    


});
```

Comment: i am using two different page check page have home if user select check box value in results page ?

Comment: i have Two different page . i have already passed value in  another page i have stored value  $checkbox1 = $_POST["S"];   i want pass this value in script but i am trying to pass  i am getting error